# How to post multiple data/data types to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Currently im stuck on this problem,

I am currently posting json to a php page which works, however I also want to post a variable to this php page aswell but dont know how to include it.

Here is the current code

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "sjfb-save.php",
    data: data, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        $('.alert').removeClass('hide');
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");

        //Demo only
        $('.alert textarea').val(JSON.stringify(fields));
    }
```

and say the variable is $example;
The variable is just a string.

and here is the code that retreives the json

```
$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: _I also want to post a variable to this php page aswell._ Just append query with this variable to the url: `url: "sjfb-save.php?var="+$example,...`

Comment: or simply add it to the json string

Answer (score 1):

You can append `GET` query with such variable to the request's URL:

```
var v = '...';
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "sjfb-save.php?var="+encodeURI(v),
    ...
});
```

Then the sent variable will be available through `$_GET` global array.

```
$_GET['var']
```

Comment: @29560 You could choose this answer as "accepted" if it solve your problem